# Use a radio button and make it hidden as well

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

Is there any way to use a radio button and make it hidden as well?

I am trying to store a value inside 4 automatically (JSP) generated radio buttons. I need to place one more radio button which will hold some default value but it should be hidden from user. Is there any way for this?

Comment: What would be the point of that? Why make it a radio button at all if it's hidden?

Comment: Just generate on more jsp radio button manually and set this css style `display:none`.

Answer (score 8):

You should avoid using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` on form field elements because this will have a negative impact on accessibility. Users who are navigating your website via the keyboard (no mouse) will not be able to tab between form elements and check/uncheck them. You could try using the following instead:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

**Update:** Due to [a known bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985), the radio button's border and dot are still visible when `appearance: none` has been applied. Setting the opacity to zero instead seems to be working for me:

```
opacity: 0;
```

Comment: Not true in this case. What visually able users do not have access to disabled users should not have access to. Screenreaders read the DOM anyway so appearance: none; will be doing the same as the others.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the question. I thought this question was about styling. I sometimes hide radio buttons and style their labels instead, because this gives me more visual control. When doing this, it's important to preserve the functionality of the radio buttons so that active and focus states remain distinguishable to all users (keyboard, mouse, etc.) and screen readers are still able to understand and announce what's happening as users interact with the control. Many screen readers will not announce elements hidden via display:none, but they have no problem with opacity:0.

Answer (score 3):

See [HTML Forms: Control Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) for:

> **hidden controls**
>       Authors may create controls that are not rendered but whose values are submitted with a form. Authors generally use this control type to store information between client/server exchanges that would otherwise be lost due to the stateless nature of HTTP (see [RFC2616]). The `INPUT` element is used to create a hidden control.

Comment: Can this answer be extended? An INPUT can not be type hidden and radio at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested to use HIDDEN FIELD for your purpose.But still,you have some other purpose for using radio button then,make your radio button hidden, by using style sheet as follow:-

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobt" value="4" style="display:none"/>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I there any reason to hidden radio button?. While loading form or page you can hide the radio button by using jQuery hide option. whenever you need you can show to the page. Otherwise you can use css - display:none option to hide a radio button from the page. Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a radio button by using the set.Visible(Boolean flag) method from javax.swing:

> myButton.setVisible (false);